# Is there any way to check the SSD of a MacOS in binary / hexadecimal?

Tags: macos, ssd, unix

Macs are based on UNIX as far as I know. Thereby I was wondering if there was any way of checking the entire content of the SSD of a macOS in binary or in hexadecimal.

EDIT: I know about xxd and such other tools available however I was looking for a way out which essentially bypasses the security (SIP) as mentioned in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hexdump` and `xxd` are available in macOS. Direct access to `/dev/disk0` is blocked by the System Integrity Protection (SIP) on newer macOS, you'll have to [disable it](https://www.easeus.com/mac-data-recovery-software/data-recovery-from-system-disk-under-new-macos.html).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616111/cant-open-physical-disk-device-in-macos-10-13).

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I was looking for a different approach :)

Comment: If you could just bypass the security, it wouldn't be particularly secure... "based on Unix" (BSD, actually) doesn't help with that, the people who added SIP are very aware of this.

Comment: interesting...as I expected! Anyway you mind going a bit more deep into it? would there be anyway to physically get data out of the drive? as at the last it's just "hardware" so maybe we could look at the binaries and decode the file. I believe that if we could get hold of the entire SSD data even if encrypted would suffice. As there definitely would be some particular space that would hold the encryption key as well. @dirkt

Comment: If you can get physical access to the SSD (take it out, connect it to a different computer) you can always get at the whole data. However, that's not (easily) possible e.g. on newer macbooks; the SSD is part of the motherboard. I haven't looked at the details of SIP, but with e.g. the [T2 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple-designed_processors#Apple_T2) and TPM, they can in principle block access to the SSD, even if you try to access the "hardware" (SSD controller) directly. Encryption is irrelevant for that. But at the moment, it's (still) easy to disable SIP...

Comment: Thanks for the support :) it was really helpful. So basically although it's tough to get the hardware out but still if one manages then it can be read/decyphered. that's pretty cool. I guess that's why FBI and other agencies have problem extracting data from recovered ios devices (If it's complicated for a PC then it's super complicated for a tiny iphone). Thanks!